# EXISTS condition in RECURSIVE CTE

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I'm trying to use "EXISTS condition in RECURSIVE CTE" **to stop recursion**, but I get SQL Error [42P19]. PostgreSQL version 13.2.
Is there a way to bypass this limitation?

The Sql-query below creates a table with node-parent relationships. I need to build a relative path from any base node to any nested node.
Example. Given the input arguments base_id(1) and rel_id(4), the result should be "1/2/4".

If you remove part EXISTS from the query, the result will be correct, BUT if there are 100+ records in depth, this will seriously affect performance.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS nodes;

CREATE TABLE nodes (
    id INT4
    , parent_id INT4
);

INSERT INTO nodes (
    id, parent_id
) VALUES (
    1, NULL
), (
    2, 1
), (
    3, 1
), (
    4, 2
), (
    5, 4
);

-- get rel path by base id 1 to rel id 4
WITH RECURSIVE r AS (
    SELECT n.id, n.parent_id, CAST(n.id AS VARCHAR) rel_path
    FROM nodes n
    WHERE n.id = 1 -- base
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT n.id, n.parent_id, CONCAT(rel_path, ' / ', n.id) rel_path
    FROM r
    JOIN nodes n ON n.parent_id = r.id
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM r r_sub
        WHERE r_sub.id = 4 -- rel
    )
)
SELECT *
FROM r
WHERE id = 4; -- rel
```

sandbox rel
https://extendsclass.com/postgresql/1a1bc61

Comment: In this situation, I can go in the reverse order and this is probably the optimal solution, but what interests me first of all is the possibility of stopping the recursion through the EXISTS expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have `r` in your query, filter can be simplified to `!=`. It will not stop alternative paths but you can additionally filter in the outmost select.

```
WITH RECURSIVE r AS (
    SELECT n.id, n.parent_id, n.id::text rel_path -- here you need to initiate rel_path
    FROM nodes n
    WHERE n.id = 1 -- base
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT n.id, n.parent_id, CONCAT(rel_path, ' / ', n.id) rel_path
    FROM r
    JOIN nodes n ON n.parent_id = r.id
    WHERE r.id != 4
)
SELECT rel_path
FROM r
where r.id = 4
```

Result: `1 / 2 / 4`

Comment: This is suitable for getting the result, but not suitable for stopping the recursion. If there are 100+ records in depth, this will seriously affect performance.

Comment: Probably you should ask another question if you have low performing query. Your original question about "using EXISTS" and finding the path was answered.

Comment: @Syzako: Your objection makes no sense. A plain `check r.id <> 4` stops the recursion just fine, and is the cheapest option. Much cheaper than your `EXISTS` expression, which wouldn't be allowed anyway. Oh, and work with an integer array instead of string concatenation for the path - cheaper & cleaner.